# Elegant and performant way to aggregate multiple Maps to a single one

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, hashmap

I have a List of Maps. All Maps have the same Keys. Now I would like to aggregate all Maps of the List to one Map by just summing up the values for each key.

It feels like there should be a better way to do this.

```java
// source
public List<Map<Integer, Long>> list_of_maps = new ArrayList<>();

// destination
private Map<Integer, Long> aggr_map = new HashMap<>();


for(Integer i : list_of_maps.iterator().next().keySet()){
    long c = 0;
    for(Map<Integer, Long> map : list_of_maps){
        c += map.get(i).getCount();
    }
    aggr_map.put(i, c);
}
```

I run this aggregation very often, so the runtime is really important...

Comment: where did `Counter/numRecordsEachSubpartition` came from?

Comment: If performance is the most important consideration, I'd stick with the solution you have now instead of using Streams, which have some overhead.

Comment: I'm assuming `aggr_map` and `numRecordsEachSubpartition` should be the same `Map`, right?

Comment: sry, i mixed up the naming -.-
fixed it now!

Comment: Does the `aggr_map` need to be a brand new map, or is it okay to add elements to one of the existing maps in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may do it like so,

```
Map<Integer, Long> numToSumMap = list_of_maps.stream()
    .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
        Collectors.summingLong(Map.Entry::getValue)));
```

Comment: I can't say it is more performant without doing any benchmark. But it is definitely more readable to me. When it comes to code readability and maintainability are of paramount importance for us.

Comment: I did small research on performance and figured out that using streams seems to impact performance negatively. See: https://blog.jooq.org/2015/12/08/3-reasons-why-you-shouldnt-replace-your-for-loops-by-stream-foreach/

Comment: But streams let you execute this in parallel and that would boost performance if you have large amount of work. The above stream based solution is parallel friendly.